Can I build sections in a SharePoint List Items
I have a SharePoint list that is pretty large and covers various actions.
Can it be separated by action? For example: recruitment; pre work, recruitment posting, interviews and post-hire stages.

I agree with Ganesh Sanap. Please kindly consider this comment as a warm follow up, I want to know if your problem has been solved. If you still have any other questions, please feel free to comment here and I'm glad to provide further support.

You can create multiple list views in your SharePoint list which can show filtered items based on specific actions you have.

You can create custom views of libraries and lists to organize and show items that are most important to you (like certain columns), to add filtering or sorting, or to have a more engaging style. You can create a personal view (that only you can see) or, if you have permissions to do so, you can create a public view for everyone who uses the list to see.

Check below Microsoft official documentations for detailed information about how to create views, how to edit views, how to apply filtering, etc.

Create, change, or delete a view of a SharePoint list or library
Use filtering to modify a SharePoint view
Edit a view of a SharePoint list - video
Creating Useful Views for SharePoint Lists & Libraries - open-source community article


OR if you want to show all items in single view only, you can apply "grouping" on your action column in SharePoint list.
Documentation: Use grouping to modify a SharePoint list or library view
